# Can I use the file command on Android?

Tags: terminal

The UNIX `file` command, which tells you what is inside a file, is seemingly not available either in Busybox or the system directory of Android.

Is there any way to run `file` on Android? (via Terminal Emulator, etc)

Preferably without having to be rooted...

Answer (score 1):

You really won't find it because it doesn't exist on Android system not even from a third party Busybox installer. But I achieved to find a solution to compile it so that I can use it on my android terminal. Here's the link *http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1612760*

Basically you just have to follow this,

*Originally posted by samveen on XDA*

After wandering around looking for an android build of the file command, I finally went ahead and compiled it myself.

The attached package contains the file binary (v5.11), the libmagic.so shared library, the associated magic files and the build specific files that I needed (over and above the source) to build it. The paths of the files are relative to '/'.

Refs:

- source: [file command website](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/)
- compiling: [Native Vim on Android](http://gdr.geekhood.net/gdrwpl/vim-android.php)

Note: Add the location of libmagic.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH to get rid of the "CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE" error. (I use /data/local/lib)

#### Code

```
 $ echo $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH /data/local/lib:/data/local/lib:/data/local/lib:/system/lib:/vendor/lib 
 $ file 

 Usage: - file  [-bchikLlNnprsvz0] [--apple]
                    [--mime-encoding] 
                    [--mime-type] [-e testname]
                    [-F separator] [-f namefile] 
                    [-m magicfiles] file ... 


  file -C [-m magicfiles]
  file [--help] 

  $ getprop | grep device [ro.cm.device]: [jordan] [ro.product.device]: [umts_jordan]
```

Download here: *http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1022807&d=1335294084*